# Get properties of "parent creating" object

Tags: php, object, backtrace

I have an object of wich I just know the Class name, let's say "A". I'm trying to acess the properties of this object. Unfortunately I'm trying to access them from another object instance, created by the first object, of a **completely** different class (nor extended or related). Simplified code below to explain the situation.

```
Class A {

    public $var; //some important stuff

    function createObjectB() {
        $b = new B();
    }
}

Class B {
  // a totally different class not related with A
}
```

This is third party code of a component in a CMS, so I can't mess with core code (or at least I think?) trying to pass the property along with the B created object without causing errors at a later time if this component gets updated.

I can acess the object from Class B due to a "layout-template" file later called in the B class, that won't be touched if the core code get's updated. This way I can't really touch neither of these classes.

Using a `debug_backtrace()` from `object B` I can see a few step back the properties of the object I need, but I think it's rather hacky to use the function this way to obtain the info I need, and I think that it's quite an intensive function to use too.

I'm quite a novice in PHP, is it just plain wrong what I'm trying to achieve? Is there any better way?

Comment: can't you pass a reference to the A class when you create B? `$b = new B($this);`

Comment: Unfortunately as I say above, It's a third party component, if I hack with core files I'm afraid I'll get in trouble later time if code gets updated from vendors. Is this correct to think or it's just a fuss?

Comment: well, then seems that what you want is use a global variable. This is a **bad pratice**, but is better that `debug_backtrace`. When you create the `B` object, or in the __construct of the `A` object, you can write `$GLOBALS['_A'] = $this;`, then you can retrive it in `B` with `$GLOBALS['_A']->var`.

Comment: Both the classes are part of the core code, I can acess the object from Class B from a "template" file later called in the class. I've edited my question to point this better now.

Answer (score 0):

Heredity is a well-established programming principle, and PHP makes use of it in your object modeling. This principle will affect the way many classes and objects relate to each other.

For example, when extending a class, subclass inherits all public and protected methods of the parent class. Unless a class overwrite these methods retain their original functionality.

This is useful for defining and abstracting functionality and allows the implementation of additional functionality in similar objects without the need to reimplement all of the shared functionality.

**Important: Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before being used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to classes that inherit from other classes and interfaces.**

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'Foo: ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function printPHP()
    {
        echo 'PHP is great.' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class bar extends Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'Bar: ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();
$foo->printItem('baz'); // Salida: 'Foo: baz'
$foo->printPHP();       // Salida: 'PHP is great' 
$bar->printItem('baz'); // Salida: 'Bar: baz'
$bar->printPHP();       // Salida: 'PHP is great'

?>
```

You must to know that you can generate new objects into another classes. But you can inherit all the properties from class A to the class B without create a new instance. For example:

```
<?php 

    Class A {

        public function something() {
            $var = 'Hello!';
            return $var;
        }
    }

    Class B extends A {

        function createObjectB() {
            echo $this->something().' I am learning classes in php';
        }
    }

    $b = new B;
    $b->createObjectB();

 ?>
```

Please visit this page http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php for more about.

Comment: Thank you Fernando, unfortunately the classes I'm working with are _not_ related in any way, they are completely separated, no extends or anything. I edited my question to highlight this better.

Comment: So. You can use too the interfaces and implements of php. Learn how this.  http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: If you don't want to use extends for inherit all the properties from the Class A to the Class B, the only way to access of the properties is creating a new instance of the class and access to them with for own variable.

Comment: Thank you, the interface feature is quite interesting! Unfortunately, I can't really touch anything in the declaration of these Classes as they are part of the core code of this third party component, so I can't implement it.